# Why does it keep saying fatal error bind parameter on a non object

Tags: php, fatal-error

```
 <?php
 include('db_conx.php');
 $username= $_POST ['username'];
  $password= $_POST ['password'];
 //Test:
 echo "<h1>Username: $username</h1>";
 echo "<h1>Password: $password</h1>";
 $mysqli=new mysqli       
 ('localhost','1800758_robbie','mypassword', '1800758_robbie');
 $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM  
 1800758_robbie.users3 WHERE username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1");
  **$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username,$password);**
 $stm->execute();
 $stmt-> store_result();
 $res=$stmt->num_rows();
 if($res == 1) {echo "You have successfully logged in.";}else{echo " the 
username and password you've supplied is not valid.";}
?>
```

I have tried reading several other posts but none match this code. I am so lost as to why I keep getting this error message. All I want to do is create a succesful login page for a forum. BTW I have all my login information correct on my end.

Comment: What do you get if you add `var_dump($stmt);` just above `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username,$password);`?

Comment: It probably means `$mysqli->prepare(...);` did not prepare the statement successfully. Print the `$stmt` object and see what error it gives you.

Comment: i have to admit i dont know what print the $stm object mains.

Comment: @War10ck was the last comment

Comment: @jd182 i used that and also JC Sama's and i get this error "bool(false) 
Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in /srv/disk11/1800758/www/robbiesgayventures.atwebpages.com/forum2/login.php on line 12"

Comment: no matter what i do the bind_param never works

Comment: @RobbieMilton, try to remove the schema name from your query `1800758_robbie` just use `FROM  users3`

Comment: @JCSama I figured out that i was typing wrong it was supposed to be user3 not users3 but now the function statement is not working it says its bound to a non object but everything else in the code above is the same

Comment: you still have something wrong in your query, check it again

Comment: @RobbieMilton This means you're `$mysqli->prepare(...)` statement is failing. I apologize for the confusion with _"print the `$stmt` object"_. After `$mysqli->prepare(...)`, add `print_r($stmt);`. This should tell you why the preparing of the statement failed.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like an error in your prepare statement. Try this:

```
"SELECT username, password FROM users3 WHERE username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1"
```

You don't need to reference the database name for the `users3` table, you already specified the table in your DB connection. If that still doesn't work make sure your table actually has fields named `username` and `password`.